# Validation based on another field

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, symfony-2.5

I am new  to this `Symfony` framework and ran into a dead end during  implementation. I am required to validate `new password` and `confirm password` fields only if `current password` of the user is entered.

I tried my best to understand the concept by going though these links,

- http://shout.setfive.com/2013/06/27/symfony2-forms-without-an-entity-and-with-a-conditional-validator/
- [Validate form fieldA based on either fieldA or fieldB in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386539/validate-form-fielda-based-on-either-fielda-or-fieldb-in-symfony-2)
- http://tomislavsantek.iz.hr/2011/03/using-symfony-postvalidator/

But turns out either the classes used are deprecated or required an entity.

The implementation of the two fields are as follows,

```
//if this field is filled
$builder->add('currentPassword', 'password', array('label'=>'Current Password',                                            
                                      'required'=>false,                                          
                                      'attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'),                                           
                                      'error_bubbling' => true,
                                      'trim' => true,
                                      'mapped' => false,
                                      'label_attr'=>array('class'=>'col-sm-4 control-label')));

//These repeated fields must be filled or must be set as required
$builder->add( 'password', 'repeated', array( 'type' => 'password',                                          
                                      'required' => false,        
                                      'invalid_message' => ErrorMessages::PASSWORDS_DO_NOT_MATCH,
                                      'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field form-control')),                                                                                   
                                      'first_options'  => array('label' => false,  
                                                                'error_bubbling' => true,
                                                                'label_attr'=>array('class'=>'col-sm-4 control-label')),
                                      'second_options' => array('label' => false,                                                                    
                                                                'label_attr'=>array('class'=>'col-sm-4 control-label'))));
```

I implemented a validation using a bunch of  `if` conditions within the controller but it would be great to learn the proper way of performing validations for a scenario such as this. :)

Thank you

**EDIT**

the user `entity`

```
    <?php
    namespace Proj\Bundle\AccountsBundle\Entity;

    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
    use Proj\Bundle\AccountsBundle\Custom\ErrorMessages;



    class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable {    

      /**
       * @Assert\Email(message=ErrorMessages::EMAIL_ADDRESS_INVALID)
       * @Assert\NotBlank(message=ErrorMessages::EMAIL_ADDRESS_EMPTY)
       */
      private $email;

      /**     
       * @Assert\NotBlank(message=ErrorMessages::PASSWORD_EMPTY, groups={"full"})
       */
      private $password;

      private $oldPassword;

      private $id;
      private $userId;
      private $name;
      private $username;



      public function __construct() {

      } 

      function setEmail ($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->username = $email;
      }

      function getEmail () {
        return $this->email;
      }

      function setPassword ($password) {
        $this->password = $password;
      }

      function getPassword () {
        return $this->password;
      }

      function setOldPassword ($oldPassword) {
        $this->oldPassword = $oldPassword;
      }

      function getOldPassword () {
        return $this->oldPassword;
      }

      function setId ($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
      }

      function getId () {
        return $this->id;
      }

      function setUserId ($userId) {
        $this->userId = $userId;
      }

      function getUserId () {
        return $this->userId;
      }

      function setName (PersonName $name) {
        $this->name = $name;
      }

      function getName () {
        return $this->name;
      }

      public function eraseCredentials() {

      }

      public function getRoles() {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
      }

      public function getSalt() {

      }

      public function getUsername() {
        return $this->username;
      }

    }
```

Comment: Could I see how do you create the form (so che `$this->createForm()`) method basically

Comment: @DonCallisto Thank you for the reply, I create the form like `$form = $this->createForm(new MyAccountForm(), $myAccountUser, array('action'=>$this->generateUrl('accounts_myaccount')));`

Comment: So, could you include `$myAccountUser` class into the question? With a bit of "luck" I think I've got the answer

Comment: @DonCallisto ohh i will.. sorry for the delay

Comment: @DonCallisto I have added the user entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your class as follows

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;

/**
 *
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"passwordVerify"})
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable {
  //all your old code here
  public function passwordVerify(ExecutionContext $context)
  {
    //your controls about password fields here
    //in case of failure you can add that snippet of code
    $context->addViolationAtPath($propertyPath,'your message here', array(), null);
  }
}
```

Of course you have to be able to access all informations into `passwordVerify` function and the quickest method to do this is to create the field `verifyPassword` into your entity so when you bind form with entity all data will be there.

That snippet of code will call automatically a callback method when you use `isValid()` form's method