# Injecting values from two form fields in one ConstraintValidator

Tags: forms, symfony, validation

I have a following task: validate form field, containing date when document was given, but to do that I need to rely on other form field - birthdate of document owner(document is valid only when it was given after specific birthday). Is there anyway to do that using custom Symfony constraint validator object, and, if it is impossible, what is the best way to make such validation - of course, I can do that in my controller after form validation, but I think this is not the best solution.

Comment: Class constraint would be more suitable here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right:) Already find solution based on this idea in another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologize to community. Answer found on additional search in following question [Symfony2 form validation based on two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170301/symfony2-form-validation-based-on-two-fields) 
Maybe it will be helpful to somebody.